# Is access to a data structure posted through PostThreadMessage() serialized by multiple receiving threads?

Tags: winapi

I want to share a data structure from one thread to two other threads with the Win32 API `PostThreadMessage()` using a [`MSG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msg) structure. I just want to know if the use of queued thread messages is serialized?

I try:

```
PostThreadMessage(thReceiver_A_Id, (int)ct + 100, (WPARAM)&generic_data, NULL);
PostThreadMessage(thReceiver_B_Id, (int)ct + 100, (WPARAM)&generic_data, NULL);
```

and expect serialized access on the receiver side:

```
MSG msg;
GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two separate receiving threads will run two independent message loops in parallel. In general, they will not be serialized with each other.

If they are just reading your queued data, that will work just fine, provided that the sending thread doesn't modify the contents of that data in any way. Otherwise, you will have to provide your own serialization to the data, such as with a critical section or mutex.

Also, do keep in mind that `PostThreadMessage()` is *asynchronous*, so it will return to the calling thread as soon as the message is queued.  Since you are passing a pointer to `generic_data`, you need to make sure that `generic_data` stays alive in memory until both receiving threads have finished processing the queued messages, otherwise you risk invalidating the pointers.

Comment: that's confirm what i have understood on my side thank you.